# reading from a USB from freeDOS

Tags: freedos

I have a nettop that doesn't have a CD driver. I need to install an OS with a USB.
It came with freeDOS OS and I don't know how to reach the USB I connected to it that has the installation for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the Windows USB bootable and then boot from the USB stick.  You may need to tweak settings in the BIOS.

Comment: How do I change the setting in the BIOS?

Comment: Check the documentation for your nettop.  There's usually a key you press when it's starting up to go into the BIOS setup.  Usually F2 or F12 - depends on the BIOS, though.